# Bootstrap 3 grid column height with a radio input, in Cordova

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a table where each row looks like something this:

```
    <div class="row table-row" ng-click="files.openItem(item)">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio">Label</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 truncate">12:00</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 truncate">Variabile</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 truncate" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#descripcion-modal">Description adkhdak kahdka</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 truncate">88</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 truncate">99</div>
    </div>
```

The relevant CSS is:

```
.table-row > div {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #35B5E5;
}

.truncate {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

A live demo can be seen here: http://plnkr.co/edit/XeRE4SW3PMamB6eoxR2q?p=preview

The height of the first column is slightly bigger than the second one, as indicated by the blue bottom border.

I wanted to have a radio button without a label. If the label text is ommited, the radio button sinks into the row border. So I removed the label tag altogether (as seen in the 3rd row of the demo), and for a while I thought that my problems are solved.

But then I deployed this code into a Cordova app on a 4.0 device. It did not render as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIHpz.png

Is there any way this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

There is an added `4px` or margin-top coming from bootstrap which is pushing the radio and eventually pushing the border line.

**Don't** wrap the radio within a `label` and set the margin-top to zero like so.

```
.table-row input[type=radio]{
     margin-top:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added your suggestion as a fourth row. In a browser, it works just fine. Unfortunately, when deployed into the Cordova app, the border is still pushed down. See here: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/JlOYW5O.png). I'm thinking maybe it's an old WebKit rendering issue? But then, how can ensure it works on a wider array of devices?